# Does LinkedIn Sales Navigator come with APIs for contact, previous roles, etc.?

Tags: linkedin-api

#linkedin
We currently have LinkedIn Sales Navigator, Recruiter, and Learning.
I am looking for LinkedIn APIs related to an individuals:

- first name
- last name
- job title
- company
- previous job title
- previous company
- if possible, email

Does this exist?  Is it included in LinkedIn Sales Navigator?
If so, is the comprehensive documentation?

(I saw the LinkedIn API that is available via the Microsoft website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/sales/api-reference/r_sales_nav_profiles/sales-navigator-profile-associations but I don't think this provides what I need as no profile details are included, just the link.)

thank you

I tried looking for the additional APIs and contacting their support which directed me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want the [Profile API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin%2Fconsumer%2Fcontext). The list of fields is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile).